# save file to folder from webService

Tags: c#

Good afternoon, I have the following data in a table in Sql

```
Comprobante Categoria
    603552       A
    624997       A
    651880       A
    672298       C
    615985       C
    613804       C
    617970       A
    625688       A
    689463       B
    611686       B
```

Then generate a console application that queries the WebService by taking the voucher number and downloading a .pdf, but it blocks me, this application has to generate a folder by Category by taking the value of the sql query from the Vouchers table and inside each folder download the invoice corresponding to that category so the invoices are sorted by category within each folder. I appreciate all the help.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string url = null;
string strSQL = "SELECT numeroComprobante,categoria FROM Comprobantes";

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("********");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strSQL, con);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var request = new Services.consultarDocumento()
                {
                    request = new Services.requestConsultaDocumento()
                    {

                        numeroComprobante = reader["numeroComprobante"],
                    }

                };

            var address = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("*********"));

            BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
            binding.Name = "basicHttpBinding";
            binding.HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.StrongWildcard;
            binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.None;

            var client = new Services.ConsultaDocumentoClient(binding, address);

            var response = client.consultarDocumento(request);

            var Factura= @return.Documento;
            }

            reader.Close();
            con.Close();

    }
  }
```

Comment: What's wrong with this code? You explain what do you want but you didn't tell what issues you are facing? Did you debug the code and check if it is executing as per your logic? Are you seeing any error?

Comment: Hi, I need to save the downloaded file to the folder that corresponds to the sql query,I downloaded the file 603552 and I have to create the folder A of the category and save it, the same with the rest of the files and their corresponding folder

Comment: @Sebastian - you haven't actually asked a question! You've just told us what you do, and that *it blocks you*? What is blocking you? What is the error? What have you tried? Which line of code fails? Please see read this https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ Good luck!

Comment: I consult a voucher number I keep it in the invoice variable, I do not know how to create the folder that corresponds to that file according to the sql query, every downloaded file should be saved in its folder according to the sql query, but before it should be created, I do not know how do it in my code